# Toggle height of div size issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following code to toggle the size of a div:

```
var position = 'expanded';
var curHeight = $('.login-div').height();
$(".login-header").click(function() {
    if (position == 'expanded') {
        $('.login-div').animate({
            height: '3.2vw'
        });
        position = 'collapsed';
    } else {
        $('.login-div').animate({
            height: curHeight
        });
        position = 'expanded';
    }
});
```

My initial div height have no default size.Its height depends on content.So i'm trying to get the height of the div and use it at my second click,to change it's size back to normal.But somehow it doesn't take the correct height.My initial div has 260 px height,but the height() says it has only 238 px ...

Comment: Can you reproduce this in `jsfiddle`

Comment: my fellow romanian you are using two different types of units

Comment: If your element has a `border` or `margin` set on it in CSS and you wish to include those in the height, try `outerHeight()`.

Comment: @madalinivascu , yes i've set it with vw , but i'm speaking of the output , if you check the dev console, it will show the size in px , not matter the measurement you'r using

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , awesome Rory , didn't knew about that , thanks a lot :) , post an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your element has a border or margin set on it in CSS and you wish to include those in the height value, use `outerHeight()`

```
var curHeight = $('.login-div').outerHeight();
```

Answer (score 4):

I've created a little example. Not sure exactly what you meant with your question. Does this illustrate what you wanted to do?

```
 var positionExpanded,
     curHeight = $('.login-div').outerHeight();

$(".login-header").click(function() {
    if (positionExpanded) {
        $('.login-div').animate({
            height: '32vw'
        });
        positionExpanded = false;
    } else {
        $('.login-div').animate({
            height: curHeight
        });
        positionExpanded = true;
    }
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsbin.com/jivezilula/4/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: yes, that was the problem,but Rory McCrossan came a little sooner with the answer..sorry

Answer (score -1):

```
var position = 'expanded';
var curHeight = $('.login-div').height();
$(".login-header").click(function() {
    if (position == 'expanded') {
        $('.login-div').animate({
            height: '3.2vw'
        });
        position = 'collapsed';
    } else {
        $('.login-div').animate({
            height: curHeight
        });
        position = 'expanded';
    }
});
```